# Shrotcuts for using namespace Ctrl + . not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 Professional, and i remember, if you are trying to add a namespace by using the shortcut when hovering over the squiggly line by pressing (Ctrl + .) it shows the namespace or "Resolve", but i am not getting that option in my VS.

I tried googling this strange behavior and i am not getting any resolution.  Could you let me know how to resolve this ?

Regards,
Ron.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a function of the Tool ReSharper, not VS built in.